# about multiprocessing in python3

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use multiprocessing to set up 2 process.
Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing 

def aaa():
    while True:
        print('aaa')

def bbb():
    while True:
        print('bbb')


if __name__=='__main__':
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=aaa())
    p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=bbb())
    p1.start
    p2.start
    p1.join
    p2.join
```

I expect it will print:

> 'aaa','bbb','aaa','bbb','aaa','bbb','aaa','bbb','aaa','bbb','aaa','bbb',

Why does it only print `aaa`, but not `bbb` ?
thank you!

Comment: `start` and `join` are functions, you need to call them instead of just stating their names: `p1.start()`, note the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `aaa`, not passing it to `Process`.

```
import multiprocessing 

def aaa():
    while True:
        print('aaa')

def bbb():
    while True:
        print('bbb')


if __name__=='__main__':
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=aaa)
    p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=bbb)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```